# Why rethrow an exception

Tags: c++

In C++, why would you want to rethrow an exception. Why not let the current catch block handle the exception. For what reasons would you rethrow an exception to another try/catch block?

Comment: Because the function containing the current catch block cannot perform its task and wants to throw an exception to indicate this.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)! Is this homework? If so, you might want to [restate your question a little](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812).

Comment: If it's not your job to handle it, why would you swallow an exception? For example, if you write a data structure that needs to do special work to recover when an object throws an exception while being inserted, you need to catch the exception to do the special work, but it's not your prerogative to handle the exception, since you have no idea what it means in that context. You catch and rethrow an exception when you want to do work when the exception occurs, but otherwise let the exception propagate normally.

Comment: For example silence an exception based on an internal state, or clean up resources before letting the exception propagate further.

Comment: @gnasher729. Why would the catch block catch the exception if it cannot handle the exception?

Comment: @Tomas Lycken. No this is not a homework, I am learning by myself

Comment: @Cameron. You read my mind. Could you please give me a practical easy example

Comment: "Why would the catch block catch the exception if it cannot handle the exception?" Perhaps it doesn't know whether it can handle it until after it's caught it. Perhaps it can't handle it but needs to take some local action (freeing resources, logging the failure, rolling back a transaction, or whatever) - although that should usually be a job for an RAII destructor. Perhaps it can add some extra information to the exception, to help diagnose the failure.

Answer (score 7):

An exception is thrown when a function cannot meet its contract (what it promises the caller it will do). When a function calls another function that throws an exception, there are four main approaches to how it might respond:

1. **Catch the exception and handle it**. This should only be done if the function is able to meet its contract despite the exception being thrown. If it catches the exception but fails to meet its contract, it is hiding a problem from the calling code.
2. **Allow the exception to propagate**. This should be done if the exception cannot be handled by this function (that is, the function is unable to meet its contract because the exception has been thrown), and if the exception exposes the appropriate information to the calling code.
3. **Catch the exception, do some clean-up and/or add extra info, and rethrow it**. This should be done if the exception cannot be handled by this function, but it needs to do some cleaning up before propagating it. It can also provide extra information to help with handling/debugging the exception (I often think of the programmer as the very last exception handler).
4. **Catch the exception and throw a different exception** (perhaps wrapping the original). This should be done if the exception cannot be handled by this function, but a different exception better expresses the problem to the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

> Why not let the current catch block handle the exception. For what reasons would you rethrow an exception to another try/catch block?

The idea behind exceptions is that you throw them at the error site and handle them down the stack, where you have enough information to handle the error.

Conversely, there are cases when you must do something in case of an error, but still don't know how to handle the error (this is the case when you rethrow).

Example:

```
void connect_and_notify(int connection_data)
{
    try
    {
        create_network_connection(connection_data); // defined somewhere else
        notify("connection open");                  // same (notify event listeners)
    }
    catch(const std::runtime_error&)
    {
        notify("connection failed");
        throw;
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
void terminal_app_controller()
{
    try
    {
        connect_and_notify(1);
    }
    catch(const std::runtime_error& err)
    {
        std::cerr << "Connection failed;\n";
        exit(1); // this is usually bad bad code but whatever
    }
}

void ongoing_server_controller()
{
    bool connected = false;
    int connection = 1;
    while(!connected)
    {
        try
        {
            connect_and_notify(1);
            connected = true;
        }
        catch(const std::runtime_error&)
        {
            connection++;
        }
    }
}
```

In the two usage scenarios, the error is handled differently (`connect_and_notify` has no way of knowing that, but still, on a failed connection it must notify listeners).

Each function has a different policy to handle the exception and this means different catch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I very much dislike anything like

```
catch (std::exception&) {
    ... // do some cleanup
    throw;
}
```

RAII is the correct solution to that problem. Even:

```
catch (std::exception&) {
    ... // do some logging here
    throw;
}
```

can be handled with RAII, although it is less intuitive.

BUT - where I *have* rethrown is any situation where 3rd-part (or vendor-supplied) code throws "generic" exceptions with state. For example, when logging telematics messages to a database, I know that I often receive duplicate copies of the same message. Each message has a unique ID - so a primary key violation in my DB is an "innocent" error that should be silently ignored.

Unfortunately, the DB framework we use doesn't throw a specific exception for PK violations - so we need to catch the generic dbexception and check what its reason code is to decide what to do. Hence:

```
catch (db::exception& e) {
    if (e.reason != db::exception::reason::pk_violation)
        throw;
}
```

Also, [piwi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/948128/piwi) mentioned internal state. An example would be

```
for (;;) {
    try {
        ...
    }
    catch (some_exception& e) {
        if (retry_count > 3)
            throw;
    }
}
```

Remember: If you are going to rethrow, always catch by reference to avoid slicing the exception object. (You should usually catch by ref anyway, but it is even more important when rethrowing)