# Why to have default exception catch if default functionality is to rethrow?

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling

In function g(), commenting line LABEL(default handler) results in same output as with it. Why do we have default catch?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

void h() { 
  //throw 1;   //A
  //throw 2.5; //B
  throw 'a'; //C
  //throw "add"; //D
}

void g() { 
  try {
    h();
  }
  catch (int) { cout << "int"; }
  catch (double) { cout << "double"; }
  catch (...) { throw; } //LABEL - commenting this line gives same result
}

void f() {
  try {
    g();
  }
  catch (char) { cout << "Char"; }
  catch (...) { throw; }
}

int main() { //main func
  try {
    f();
  }
  catch (...) { cout << "Unknown"; }
  return 0;
}
```

Why is default catch needed?

Comment: In this case probably not, but check out the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152201/why-rethrow-an-exception to see some examples where catching an exception only to rethrow it may be justified / unavoidable.

Comment: Even without a default rethrow it executes as if default throw is present. How to understand such behavior?

Comment: This is kind of like having a `defualt: break;` label. Pointless, but complete in a sense. And may be required to appease some static analysis tools that emit silly warnings.

Comment: When an exception is thrown, the call stack will unwind until there is a catch statement that matches the type of the exception. Since the exception thrown in `h()` is of type char neither of the non-default catch statements (that match int and double)  in `g()` will catch it. If nothing catches it `g()` will be removed from the call stack. The next try-catch block is in `f()`, and here the catch(char) will catch the exception.

Answer (score 1):

To me question is unclear and could be interpreted in two ways:

Why does a default catch-mechanism exist at all: the other answers give meaningful answers).

Why does `g` have a default `catch` with `throw;`, and I see two possibilities: it documents that other exceptions have been considered, and it is easier to debug that case (by putting a breakpoint on it).

Answer (score 0):

The default catcher exists to catch every exception that are not explicitly handled. 
They are cases where you can be sure of which exceptions could be thrown, and default catcher is a little paranoid. 
But let's say you want to catch one exception type to do something specific and you want to execute the same handler for all the other cases, the default handler prevent duplicates !

Comment: This answer would be "better" if it explicitly answered the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is you catch an exception which was not caught by the previous `catch` statements but you're throwing it further so that it can be caught elsewhere. It works the same as if the `catch(...)` statement wasn't there because if it is not, the exception not being caught by the proper `catch` goes higher to another `try` blocks (from `g()` to `f()` to `main()`) until it gets handled (in your case it is handled in `main`). If there is no `catch` to handle the exception then the system takes it over.

Note that `throw`ing an exception in `catch(...)` is **NOT** default behavior. It is something you implemented in your code by adding `throw`. If you did e.g. `cout << "..."` then it would work differently comparing to not having `catch(...)`, in which case the exception would be handled by `f()` and then by `main()`

Comment: Is it that, till an exception thrown is not handled it propagates?

Comment: @VishvajeetT yes, simething needs to happen to a thrown exception, it can't disappear. that's why in the end, when there is no `catch` for a thrown exception, the OS takes care of it (most often by terminating the program with a message "unhandled exception")

Comment: This answer would be "better" if it explicitly answered the question being asked.